# Problem uploading to board

Tags: uploading, arduino-duemilanove

```
avrdude: stk500_getsyn(): not in sync_resp=0*00
avrdude: stk500_disable: protocol error, expect=0*14,resp=0*51
```

These are the errors occurring when I am trying to upload to the board.
I've tried all the suggestions that suggested in this. When I am trying to burn the bootloader the same error is showing.

Comment: You forgot to add the link referred by "this".

Comment: What board and serial port have you selected?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got the exact error (maybe another sync error), but what helped in my case (in this order, try again every time):

- Reinsert the USB cable
- Use a different (shorter) USB cable
- Put the USB cable in another USB port
- Restart the Arduino IDE
- Restart the computer
- Reinstall the Arduino IDE
- Go to device drivers (control panel), check for COM ports, remove Arduino and reinstall